# Синтаксис современно HTML

Tags: html, валидация, php

Пожалуйста, ответьте на вопрос по поводу html5 и современных требований w3c.

Какие требования в настоящее время касаются использования кавычек в коде html? Вопрос касается одинарных и двойных кавычек. До настоящего времени я писал код так:

```
echo "<img src='$my_url' />";
```

На мой предыдущий вопрос я получил совет делать вот так:

```
 echo "<img src=\"$my_url\" />";
```

То есть в коде html должны быть именно двойные кавычки. Прошу грамотных людей помочь мне разобраться в данном вопросе.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Согласно [спецификации HTML5.1 Nightly](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/introduction.html#a-quick-introduction-to-html):

> Значения атрибутов могут быть без кавычек, если они не содержат пробелов или любого из символов " ' ` = < или >. В остальных случаях значение должно быть обрамлено одинарными или двойными кавычками. Также значения могут быть опущены вместе с символом '=', если являются пустой строкой

```
<!-- empty attributes -->
<input name=address disabled>
<input name=address disabled="">

<!-- attributes with a value -->
<input name=address maxlength=200>
<input name=address maxlength='200'>
<input name=address maxlength="200">
```

От себя хочу добавить, что делать однотипное обрамление гораздо удобнее по нескольким причинам:

1. В случаях, если значение изменится, не придется лезти в файл и ставить эти кавычки
2. Если это значение изменится неожиданно, то можно получить проблемы с версткой
3. Просто красиво, когда весь код выполнен в едином стиле

Какие именно это будут кавычки - не важно, лишь бы между ними не было такого же символа в значении атрибута. Но чаще встречаются двойные.

Answer (score 2):

Стандарт HTML5

Версия W3C Candidate Recommendation от 4 февраля 2014

Пункт 8.1.2.3 Attributes

[Стандарт  HTML5  8.1.2.3](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#attributes-0)

Атрибуты могут быть указаны четырьмя различными способами:

1. Пустой синтаксис: `<input disabled>`.
   Допускается когда аттрибут принимает только однозначное значение себя же или пустую строку.
2. Без кавычек: `<input value=yes>`. Допускается когда значение не имеет пробелы, кавычки U+0022 ("), апострофы U+0027 ('), всякие знаки (U+003D) "=", (U+003C) "<", (U+003E) ">", или обратные кавычки U+0060 (`) и не принимает пустой строки.
3. Одинарные кавычки: `<input type='checkbox'>`. Допускается, когда значение не имеет другие одинарные ковычки в своем составе.
4. Двойные кавычки: `<input name="be evil">`. Допускается когда значение не содержит других двойных кавычек.

Правда, когда вы пишете в XHTML, предпочтение отдается двойным кавычкам. Поэтому в большинстве случаев используют двойные кавычки как более строгий вариант.

Answer (score 0):

насколько мне известно в html5 при простом содержимом кавычки рекомендуется убрать, то есть   `echo "<img src=$filename >";`

Comment: этого не может быть. Я протестую.